# ASP.net How to enable a theme

Tags: asp.net, treeview, controls, skin

I have a basic question that I can't seem to resolve using Google (Or I'm using the wrong combination of keywords).

I Have an application of which I have access to the Masterpages and the ASPX. I don't have access to the code behind; Within that application I have a theme folder and a skin that I have created.

I have attempted to skin a Treeview and have added the following to the control on the aspx document SkinId="trview" (the name of the skin file without the extension).

This alone is not affecting the resulting output. I seem to remember that there is a line of code that should be added to the masterpage to tell the application to use the theme but I can't seem to find what it is.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the theme in the masterpage, but in the web.config of the application

```
<system.web>
  <pages theme="myTheme">
</system.web>
```

or in the page directive of your page using the masterpage

```
<%@ Page Theme="myTheme" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This may be the crucial bit that I am missing as the theme is not defined there.

Answer (score 0):

For all webforms, go to web.config, and edit the `<pages`> tag

```
    <pages theme="Theme1">
      ......
```

**Remember**: Theme is not skin file, skin files are contained in themes

Comment: It turns out that I have access to web.config and I have already added the theme there in the past. Thanks for your time.